# Rails database migrations problem 4.2 to 5.0 - boolean but default expression is of type integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upgrade

O.k. so I finally got a rails server to load with Rails 5.0.0 and ruby 2.5.8 (I'm upgrading from ruby 2.2.4 and rails 4.2.0).

I don't have any sll issues.

I'm now at the "ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError" level.

Basically I haven't created the tables in my db (the db is already created in postgres).

When I run the bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development I get the following:

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: column "root_comment" is of type boolean but default expression is of type integer HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

I've read a ton, and it seems rails 5 changed both migration scripts and how to define columns in postgres.

Do I need to label my migration script with something like [4.2 or 5.0] or do I actually need to change the type (further screwing up my app)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the offending migration look like? I'd guess that your migrations were written for a database that doesn't have a native boolean type (such as MySQL or SQLite) so you have `default: 0` where PostgreSQL (which does have a native boolean type) would want `default: false`.

Comment: So here's what I have for the offending column in the create_table in the first migration: t.boolean "root_comment",           default: 0, null: false

Comment: Change it to `t.boolean :root_comment, default: false, null: false` and you should be fine.